# Shiny ‘remove tab’ function causing auto deletion of newly created tab when selected

Tags: r, button, shiny, tabs

Having a shiny delete tab regression issue where the remove tab function was working until new functionality was added to dynamically add data table and plot into a new tab in Shiny.

**Scenario:**

1. User selected data from local computer
2. User makes selection from drop down list
3. Click on Add new tab
4. Click on the new tab

**Result:** New tab auto deletes after step 4

**Data:** Any simple csv table with two columns A and B will replicate the result below

**Desired result:** Prevent auto delete and only delete selected tab via clicking on remove button

**Problem area tagged in code below:** # Delete selected tab logic. If this part of the logic is commented out auto remove issue is gone but cannot manually remove tabs by user.

Thanks for looking into my problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(data.table)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = "Stackoverflow help", id = "tabs",
             
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        fileInput("file", "Upload data",
                                  accept = c(
                                    "text/csv",
                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                    ".csv")
                        ),
                        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                        actionButton("append", "Add new tab"),
                        uiOutput('tabnamesui')
                      ),
                      mainPanel( 
                        
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  userfile <- reactive({
    input$file
  })
  
  filereact <- reactive({
    read.table(
      file = userfile()$datapath,
      sep = ',',
      header = T,
      stringsAsFactors = T
    )
  })
  
  tabsnames <- reactive({
    names(filereact())
  })
  
  output$tabnamesui <- renderUI({
    req(userfile())
    selectInput(
      'tabnamesui',
      h5('Tab names'),
      choices = as.list(tabsnames()),
      selected="",multiple = FALSE
    )
  })
  
  tabnamesinput <- reactive({
    input$tabnamesui})
  
  #Append selected tab logic
  observeEvent(input$append,{
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(input$tabnamesui, 
                       sidebarPanel(
                         actionButton(paste0("remove_", input$tabnamesui), "Delete")),
                       mainPanel(
                         DTOutput(paste0("table",input$tabnamesui)),
                         plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$tabnamesui))
                       )
              )
    )
  })
  
  # Delete selected tab logic
    observeEvent(lapply(grep(pattern = "^remove_", x = names(input), value = TRUE), function(x){input[[x]]}),{
     if(input$tabs != "Home"){
       removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
       updateSelectInput(session, "tabnamesui", selected = input$tabnamesui) 
       # keep the selection when re-rendering sidebarPanel
     }
   })
  
  #New tab logic to prevent inserting same tab twice with enable/disable action button
  forcecombine = function(idtab,checker) {
    colnames(idtab) = colnames(checker)
    rbind(idtab,checker)
  }
  
  checker<-as.data.frame("checker")
  idtab<-as.data.frame("checkers")
  
  #only allow tab entry once   
  observeEvent(input$append, {
    idtab <- paste0(tabnamesinput())
    idtab<-as.data.frame(idtab)
    checkerx<-forcecombine(idtab,checker) 
    repeated<-length(grep(idtab,checkerx))
    
    if(repeated==1)  
    {
      shinyjs::disable("append")
      
    }
    else {shinyjs::enable("append")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(tabnamesinput(), {
    shinyjs::enable("append")
    lapply(tabnamesinput(), function(x) {
      df <- as.data.table(filereact()[[as.name(tabnamesinput())]])
      output[[paste0('table',x)]] <- renderDT({df})
      output[[paste0("plot",input$tabnamesui)]] <- renderPlot(boxplot(df,data=df, main="", xlab="", ylab=""))
      })
  })
  
  shinyjs::disable("append")
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    shinyjs::enable("append")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the button has been clicked.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = "Stackoverflow help", id = "tabs",

             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        fileInput("file", "Upload data",
                                  accept = c(
                                    "text/csv",
                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                    ".csv")
                        ),
                        #checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                        actionButton("append", "Add new tab"),
                        uiOutput('tabnamesui')
                      ),
                      mainPanel( 

                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  userfile <- reactive({
    input$file
  })

  filereact <- reactive({
    read.table(
      file = userfile()$datapath,
      sep = ',',
      header = T,
      stringsAsFactors = T
    )
  })

  tabsnames <- reactive({
    names(filereact())
  })

  output$tabnamesui <- renderUI({
    req(userfile())
    selectInput(
      'tabnamesui',
      h5('Tab names'),
      choices = as.list(tabsnames()),
      selected="",multiple = FALSE
    )
  })

  tabnamesinput <- reactive({
    input$tabnamesui})

  #Append selected tab logic
  observeEvent(input$append,{
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(input$tabnamesui,
                       sidebarPanel(
                         actionButton(paste0("remove_", input$tabnamesui), "Delete")),
                       mainPanel(
                         #uiOutput("tabsets") #This is where I think something is broken
                         DTOutput(paste0("table",input$tabnamesui)),
                         plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$tabnamesui))
                       )
              )
    )

  })
  
  # Delete selected tab logic
  observeEvent(lapply(grep(pattern = "^remove_", x = names(input), value = TRUE), function(x){input[[x]]}),{
    if(input$tabs != "Home"){
      if (input[[paste0("remove_",input$tabs)]]) { ## remove tab only if delete button has been clicked
        removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
        updateSelectInput(session, "tabnamesui", selected = input$tabnamesui) # keep the selection when re-rendering sidebarPanel
      }
    }
  })

  #New tab logic to prevent inserting same tab twice with enable/disable action button
  forcecombine = function(idtab,checker) {
    colnames(idtab) = colnames(checker)
    rbind(idtab,checker)
  }

  checker<-as.data.frame("checker")
  idtab<-as.data.frame("checkers")

  #only allow tab entry once
  observeEvent(input$append, {
    idtab <- paste0(tabnamesinput())
    idtab<-as.data.frame(idtab)
    checkerx<-forcecombine(idtab,checker)
    repeated<-length(grep(idtab,checkerx))

    if(repeated==1)
    {
      shinyjs::disable("append")

    }
    else {shinyjs::enable("append")
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$tabnamesui, {
    shinyjs::enable("append")
    output[[paste0("plot",input$tabnamesui)]] <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
    lapply(tabnamesinput(), function(x) {
      df <- as.data.table(filereact()[[as.name(tabnamesinput())]])
      output[[paste0('table',x)]] <- renderDT({
          df
          #subsetdata()[[x]]
        })})
  })

  shinyjs::disable("append")

  observeEvent(input$file, {
    shinyjs::enable("append")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn from this example.